# SoundPool not playing after 3 second of opening my activity

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I am trying  to play a sound when a user clicks on a button, This works well if I click the button wothin the first 3-5 seconds of when the activity is open however if I wait more then 3-5 seconds there is no sound. I am also not getting any error regarding the sound....

Any ideas would be appriciated!

UPDATE: This is happening only on my HTC. If I try this on a Samsung Galaxy S 2 it works fine!!!!

In my logcat is says: "AudioHardwareQSD: AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby" any workaround for this???

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(16, AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0);
    mAudioManager= (AudioManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    mSoundPoolMap.put(1, mSoundPool.load(mcontext, R.raw.tap, 1));}



       @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {   
            float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(1), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1);}
```

Comment: What is the int value returned by `mSoundPool.play()` in both cases?

Comment: Im getting value 1 for the sound within the 3 second. value 2 for the one after. Not getting value 0 for either...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got this to work not the best but it works...

Checked to see if the device is from HTC and then created a dummy notification that plays a sound. Also you have to make sure that your file is MP3 not wav or OGG...

```
public static void playSound(int index)
{

    String m_strManufacture = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    Log.i(TAG, "Device Name: " + m_strManufacture);
    if (m_strManufacture.equals("HTC"))
    {


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, mContext.getClass());
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        // PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        // mContext.getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.ringer);
        notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourpackages/raw/" + sound);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
    else {//Do the soundpool work....}
```